# Access newline becoming _x000D_

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula, newline

I'm trying to make a report in access derived from data I have in excel. So I import my excel sheet in access using the external data options, but my newlines keep appearing as "_x000D_"

As a example I use a excel sheet with 4 columns all with a title and all with 1 row of data containing in order from left to right:

```
="a"&char(10)&"b" 
="a"&char(13)&"b" 
="a"&char(10)&char(13)&"b" 
="a"&char(13)&char(10)&"b"
```

In my excel sheet I have tried changing the newlines to everything I could think of but the two that appeared to have done something are char(10) and char(13) however char(10) doesn't appear in access at all and char(13) appears to become "_x000D_"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [How to import from Excel and keep the line breaks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9c258bd7-f357-4b66-9dbe-3df98855abcc/how-to-import-from-excel-and-keep-the-line-breaks?forum=accessdev) :

> Excel uses line-feed character (ASCII 10) as the line separator, while Access uses the combination of carriage-return + line-feed (ASCII 13 followed by ASCII 10) as the line separator.
>
> After importing, you can use the Replace function to replace Chr(10) with Chr(13)+Chr(10).  For example, you could execute a query like this:

```
UPDATE ImportedExcelTable SET MyField = Replace([MyField], Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10));
```

So the only correct way to put a newline in an Excel cell is your first version:

```
="a"&char(10)&"b"
```

Then after importing the table, use the Update query to replace the `Lf` with Access newlines `CrLf`.