# How to remove newline characters so it doesn't produce _x000D_ when reading excel files in Python

Tags: python, excel

I try to read Excel files from a series of folders where each folder contains lots(hundreds literally) of Excel files.
This is the process I've been doing:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

def read_files(path):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for each in os.listdir(path):
        sub_path = path+"/"+each
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(sub_path, "*.xlsx"))
        for f in files:  
            df = pd.read_excel(f)
            data = data.append(df)
    df2 = df2.append(data)
    return df2
df = read_files("...my_path")
```

However, it converts newline characters in the data that it read from excel files to `_x000D_`. For example, if a particular cell value is:

```
abcde
```

It becomes:

```
abcde_x000D_
```

How can I eliminate this, and actually remove the newlines at the reading step, so that it doesn't produce `_x000D_`?

Comment: @RoyBubis' solution is applied after the data is read into dataframes. My answer attempts to handle before reading into pandas. You might try both and see which is more performant for you.

Comment: @RoyBubis yes this actually gets rid of those characters, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167807/access-newline-becoming-x000d), it seems that Excel uses `\n` `chr(10)` as newline, but your files have `\r\n` `chr(13)chr(10)`. One way to avoid this is to perform a replace operation. Every time you see `\r\n`, replace it with `\n`. I modify the file in buffer before sending to `pandas`.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

def read_files(path):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for each in os.listdir(path):
        sub_path = path+"/"+each
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(sub_path, "*.xlsx"))
        for f in files:
            with open(f, 'rb') as fp:
                text = fp.read().replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
            df = pd.read_excel(text)
            data = data.append(df)
    df2 = df2.append(data)
    return df2
df = read_files("...my_path")
```

Comment: It gave this error: `ValueError: negative seek value -1`