# Removing _x000D_ from Text Records in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a Pandas data frame that I imported from an Excel file. One of the columns looks like the following:

```
Link
=========
A-324
A-76_x000D_\nA-676
A-95
A-95_x00D_n\nA-495
...
```

I was able to use regex to remove the `\n` characters, but I am unable to remove `_x000D_`. Does anyone know what this is? Why am I unable to use traditional remove methods?

Here is what I've done:

```
dat['Link'] = dat['Link'].replace("_x000D_", " ")
dat['Link'] = dat['Link'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167807/access-newline-becoming-x000d/36216905#36216905

Comment: @X33 I'm not using Microsoft Access, so I cannot use those commands

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `.str` because you are not working directly with a string, but with a Series:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Link':['A-324','A-76_x000D_\nA-676','A-95','A-95_x000D_n\nA-495']})

dat['Link'] = dat['Link'].str.replace("_x000D_", " ")
dat['Link'] = dat['Link'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
           Link
0         A-324
1    A-76 A-676
2          A-95
3  A-95 n A-495
```

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this problem when loading text columns containing carriage returns from xlsx files.

This solved it for me:

```
df['my_col'] = df['my_col'].astype(str).apply(openpyxl.utils.escape.unescape)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to handle all string columns in dataframe (like I needed):

```
for str_col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    df[str_col] = df[str_col].astype(str).apply(openpyxl.utils.escape.unescape)
```

or the same with the `replace()` function